# testing DOM elements with phantomjs/casperjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, phantomjs, casperjs

I've got an AJAX-based javascript application which I would like to cover with interface tests. For example, I would like to write a test that loads my website (from a given URL) and checks if there are some DOM elements (given ids and given classes) that exist.

The problem is that when I enter the URL in a browser, my application has a `Loading...` label displayed and an AJAX request is sent beneath. When AJAX response arrives, some processing is done and the right webpage content is displayed (`Loading...` label is hidden). So far I've got this code:

```
casper.test.begin('Main page test', 2, function suite(test) {

    casper.start('http://xxx.yyy.zzz/', function() {
        test.assertTitle('My page name', 'page title is set correctly');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertExists('#tabsListArea', 'tabs area is found');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

This is the error message I get:

```
FAIL tabs area is found
#    type: assertExists
#    file: mypath/.../casperjs/casper-test.js:11
#    code: test.assertExists('#tabsListArea', 'tabs area is found');
#    subject: false
#    selector: "#tabsListArea"
⚠  looks you did not use begin() which is mandatory since 1.1
```

Can someone please point me out what can I do to make phantomjs/casperjs wait until the AJAX response arrives and is processed by the JS engine so that I can make all assertions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried any of the waitFor functions. You could try something like this:

```
casper.test.begin('Main page test', 2, function suite(test) {

    casper.start('http://xxx.yyy.zzz/', function() {
        test.assertTitle('My page name', 'page title is set correctly');
    });

    casper.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            return $('loading label').is('hidden');
        });
    }, function then() {    // step to execute when check() is ok
        test.assertExists('#tabsListArea', 'tabs area is found');
    }, function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
        this.echo("Timeout: page did not load in time...").exit();
    });

    casper.run(function() {
       test.done();
   });
});
```

You could then play around with the waitTimeout option so you give the page enough time to load. It isn't a perfect solution but it could work in this case.

Comment: 1 hour of searching then I find this awesome answer.. this is also a great answer to detect if a javascript object has been created.