# Karma Test: scope.$on('$destroy') never called when element is moved to body element

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that moves an element from wherever it is to be a child of the `body` element.

```
.directive('prependToBody', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element(document).find('body').prepend(element);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        console.log("prependToBody DESTROY");
        element.remove();
      });
    }
});
```

This works as expected in the app, but when I use it in a Karma (Jasmine) unit test, the `$destroy` event is never fired. **Why doesn't `$destroy` fire in the unit test?**

Comment: Are you not calling [`scope.$destroy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy)?

Comment: nope, I'm not calling `scope.$destroy()`, but if I comment out the line that `prepend`s to body it works.

Comment: Are you using PhantomJS or a "real" browser to run your tests? It might be useful for debugging this problem to run the tests in a different browser.

Comment: could you also show your spec ?

Comment: I used PhantomJS and Chrome. It happens in both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [testing DOM elements with phantomjs/casperjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925504/testing-dom-elements-with-phantomjs-casperjs)

Comment: Did you actually read that Question @PaulSweatte? I don't see any resemblance except for the fact that they both have to do with JS testing, but they are not even about the same test runner nor framework.